# Selector to match anchor and div hover state is not matching hyperlinks

Tags: html, css

My page markup is formed as follows:

```
<a href="#Products">
    <div id="Tag">
        <span>A website hyperlink</span>
    </div>
</a>

#Tag {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.161));
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 107px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 527px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 55px;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
```

As you can see color is explicitly set on the container.

I'd like to change the color on hover.

```
a:hover {
    color: red !important;
}
```

```css
a:hover {
 color: red !important;
}

#Tag {
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 527px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<a href="#Products">
    <div id="Tag">
        <span>A hyperlink</span>
    </div>
</a>
```

Is there another selector to match this hyperlink markup?

Comment: you need to target the span element `a:hover span {}` and no need !important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
a:hover * {
 color: red !important;
}

#Tag {
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 527px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<a href="#Products">
    <div id="Tag">
        <span>A hyperlink</span>
    </div>
</a>
```